# TYPO3 8.7.26 RealURL is generating infinite new URL data

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, realurl

I have a weird problem on TYPO3 8.7.26 with RealURL 2.6.1 installed. It's generating infinite URL data for page uid 1. It generates thousands of records where speaking url part is just `/` and Original URL is `L=0&id=1`.

That happens only on page id 1 and nowhere else. Does this happen to anyone else here?

I would appreciate any suggestion on how to debug this issue.  I have already tried to disable any extensions that could in my opinion interfere with RealURL, but no luck :/